# Composer failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, windows, cmd, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

am trying to install `illuminate/html` package in Laravel 5.1 using command `composer require illuminate/html` . But I get this error.

```
[ErrorException]                                                             
file_put_contents(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin): 
failed to open stream:  Permission denied

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update]
[--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] 
[--sort-packages] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

I believe Problem is permission to access that folder, I tried to remove read only protection but the protection return by default.

[image]

Am running Windows10

Comment: Try running cmd as administrator

Comment: I did not succeed on that, however I decide to install the package manually

Comment: What are you using to run it locally on Windows?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem recently, and needed to change the permissions of my folders.

By running:
`php artisan cache:clear`
`chmod -R 777 storage vendor`
`composer dump-autoload`

I was able to give all the permissions required to open files and write to them etc

Comment: Had same problem but I'm using Sail for developing. sudo chmod -R 777 storage vendor worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the **Windows Command Prompt** as an Administrator -- this worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I put this solution here in case it works for someone else.

On my system (Windows 10), I had marked both the vendor folder and the composer.json file in my project folder as `hidden`, because of reasons. The error message went away when I unhid the folders and the json files, and ran the command again. I did not need to restart my command line in Administrator mode. (In fact, trying this in Administrator mode did not work either, until I changed the file and folder properties to unhidden.)