# Permission denied error when running Composer config generator in Windows

Tags: php, windows, environment-variables, composer-php, config

I'm encountering a "Permission denied" error when trying to run Composer commands in Windows. I've tried running the command prompt/PowerShell as an administrator, but the issue persists. Here are the details:

```
Error message:
Do you confirm generation [yes]? yes

In JsonFile.php line 178:
                                                                                                 
  file_put_contents(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Steps I've taken:

- Tried running the command prompt/PowerShell as an administrator.
- Verified that I have the necessary permissions to write to the specified file/directory.
- Attempted to initialize a Composer project in a different directory, but still encountered the same error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVFec.png)

I'm using Windows [Version 22H2] and Composer [version 2.5.8].
Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to run the console as admin?

Comment: @BagusTesa yes i did. :(

Comment: is your working [directory hidden by any chance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62132430)?